# Animate DIV to full height and toggle back to defined height

Tags: javascript, animation, height, jquery-animate

I am trying to animate the div to its full height when a button is pressed and come back to its original height if the button is clicked again. The full height of the div is auto as it contains text with different word counts. I tried doing the below codes but it does not work properly.

The CSS :

```
.category_brief{
    text-align:justify;
    height:100px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Example 1 : This code does not animate the div when opening to full height , but animates while coming back to old height.

```
$(".slide").toggle(function(){
    $('.category_brief').animate({height:'100%'},200);
  },function(){
    $('.category_brief').animate({height:100},200);
  });
```

Example 2 : The output of this code is the same as of Example 1

```
var toggle = true, oldHeight = 0;

$('.slide').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var $ele = $('.category_brief');
    var toHeight = ((toggle = !toggle) ? oldHeight : newHeight);

    oldHeight = $ele.height();
    var newHeight = $ele.height('auto').height();
    $ele.animate({ height: toHeight });

});
```

Example 3 : This code animates the div to its full height but does not toggle.

```
    var slide = $('.slide');
    var slidepanel = $('.category_brief');
  // On click, animate it to its full natural height
  slide.click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
    var oldHeight, newHeight;

    // Measure before and after
    oldHeight = slidepanel.height();
    newHeight = slidepanel.height('auto').height();

    // Put back the short height (you could grab this first
    slidepanel.height(oldHeight);
    slidepanel.animate({height: newHeight + "px"});
  });
```

If possible please provide a bit explanation also as i am a newbie..

**Update :** Solved by the idea from @chazm..

@chazm : thanks for the idea. I got it working by combining 1st and 3rd example ... Here is the code in case anyone needs it .

```
var slidepanel = $('.category_brief');
    $(".slide").toggle(function(){
    var oldHeight, newHeight;

    // Measure before and after
    oldHeight = slidepanel.height();
    newHeight = slidepanel.height('auto').height();

    // Put back the short height (you could grab this first
    slidepanel.height(oldHeight);
    slidepanel.animate({height: newHeight + "px"})
  },function(){
    $('.category_brief').animate({height:100},300);
  });
```

Comment: @Wesley Murch : Its removed now ....

Answer (score 0):

Working with 'auto' height it always quite tricky. I think there are different issues in your examples.

1) Browser can't define correct 100% height. Possible solutions - define height to all its parents. Either set it to 100% (till html tag) or set closest parent as relative (because height is calculated from closest relative parent). If you want to animate div to 100% of the entire page - think of the absolute positioning

2)The same as above i assume

3)When this code supposed to toggle back  it can't determine that it should become lower that it is now. Not absolutely sure why though. Probably because 'auto' height from 100% is set to something wrong. You may check in firebug what value it has on the computed tab after that function is toggled back. Probably it will give you a clue

Try to combine 2) and 3). The idea - if toggle  is true (it shoud be lowered) then set  newHeight = slidepanel.height('100').

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends on your implementation needs. If you know that at first the div should be 100px etc in height and when you click, it maximizes to an unknown height, the following solution would work. If you had a structure similar to

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="wrapper">Content of unknown length here</div>
</div>
```

and css

```
div.wrapper { position:relative; height:100px; overflow:hidden; }
div.outer { position:absolute; height:auto; }
```

then you'd get a div that is 100px in height, with the content that doesn't fit in 100px cut off. Now when you press the desired button, you could get the height of the wrapper div, since it is a long as it's content is (even though you only see the top 100px) and set the outer div's height according to it. Like so

```
var newHeight = $('div.wrapper').height();
$('div.outer').animate({height:newHeight},200);
```

Which would then animate the outer div to display the whole contents. When you click the button again, you could just do

```
$('div.outer').animate({height:'100px'},200);
```

And you would again have only the 100px height.